# Shouldn't this code change the number on the screen when the buttons are tapped?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey guys I'm new to flutter, and I'm messing around trying to explore widgets and functions, and I got stuck. I'll appreciate any help and thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int number = 0;

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: (Text("Flutter", style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          )
          ),//title
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("$number", style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 55,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),)
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), label: 'home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'home'),
        ],

        onTap: (int number) => number++
        )
      )
    );

  }
}
```

Hey guys, I'm new to flutter and still trying to figure things out, but I was under the assumption that this cocde should change the number on the screem, however, the value remains 0
What did I get wrong?

Comment: in your `onTap` value you should put `setState` function so the `number` can be updated, you should try to read/watch the first template that flutter gave you when you create a new project. it should be explained all of it

Comment: and tbh what does you expect the code did? increment the `int number = 0` ? or using the bottomNavigationBar, because it confusing to see you design you want to made the number increase but using bottomnavbar?

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain how Flutter Widgets work (briefly).

Flutter Widgets use declarative UI returned by the `build` method. It means that a widget just returns 'a blue print' of the UI, according to the current state and properties (see below).

**UI = f(state / properties)**
*It means that for one state/properties, the UI is always the same*

There are 2 kind of widgets in Flutter:

- StatelessWidget which only depend on properties: the build method is called only when a property changes
- StatefullWidget which has a state (`number`in your example) and props: the build method is called either when a property changes or when the state changes.

But in the later, Flutter doesn't know when the state changes. So you MUST tell him that the state has changed by calling the method `setState`.

So your code should be

```dart
onTap: () => setState(() { number++; });
```

To go deeper on Widget and setState:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: I solved I was placed the number under the build function